Trust PSBT Coldcard
I sent a psbt through HWI to my coldcard for signing (it is a multisig tx created with one of the keys in the CC at m/48h/0h/0h/2h) and I am getting the error:

HWI.hwilib.errors.BadArgumentError: Coldcard Error: Unknown multisig
wallet

Anyone know why that is? I enabled TrustPSBT to TrustPSBT, so I'm assuming that I don't need to register the wallet in the coldcard (I am actively trying not to, in fact).
Thanks
